# How do I redirect into react-router from express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, react-router

I'm adding authentication into my app, which uses react-router. I've patterned the client routing after the [auth-flow](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow) example in react-router, but using passport instead of the localstorage that the example uses. this all works fine.

The next step is protecting routes I am defining for express in `server.js`. I could send a redirect to `/#/login`, but this feels brittle. What's the best way to derive a URL *on the server side* to a login route served by react-router?

Here's what I have now in my `server.js`, which works, but feels brittle:

```
app.get('/protected',
    // redirecting to #/login seems bad: what if we change hashhistory, etc.
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/#/login'}),
    function(req, res) {
     res.render('whatever');
    });
```

Comment: more code examples of what you tried pls.

Comment: Time to give a feedback?

Answer (score 2):

Config route on express to get all routes and routing with react-router, in this way, ejem.
(I hope this can help you)

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('*', (req,res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'))).listen(3000,() => console.log('Server on port 3000'))
```

**routes.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRedirect } from 'react-router'

import App from '../views/app.jsx'

const Routes = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return(
            <Router history={ browserHistory }>
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                    <IndexRedirect to="/dashboard"/>
                    <Route path="dashboard" name="Dashboard" component={App} />
                    <Route path="pages" name="Pages" component={Pages} />
                    <Route path="/:Id" component={Page}/>
                    <Route path="/:Id/inbox" name=':ids' component={Inbox}/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="*" component={App}>
                    <IndexRedirect to="/dashboard" />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Routes />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: `app.get('*')` will render the html page for static files like css and js. How to get around that?