# How to use react-router with express router?

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have project with **client** and **server** folderds

**Client:** i have react redux react-router app, **port: localhost:3000**

**Server:** i have express server with express.Router()
and my app bundled with webpack from client and this app avalable on '/' **port: localhost:3001**

When i am starting webpack-dev-server in **CLIENT(port:3000)** folder every route works as i wants then i am starting express server with nodemon  **SERVER(port:3001)** and facing this problem :

Problem i faced is when i follow any Route on **SERVER(port:3001)** except '/'
i am getting 404 error by Express.
So can anyone explain me how to use **react-router and express** together, so all my routes from bundled app will works as they works in webpack-dev-server while development

For example we have 2 Routes:

```
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
```

And we Have server.js with express app:

```
 app.get('*', (req,res) => 
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html')))
```

When i am getting 'localhost:3001/' Express sending index.html
Then i am getting 'localhost:3001/test'  And Express throw Error 404

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect into react-router from express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105453/how-do-i-redirect-into-react-router-from-express)

Comment: react router will know nothing about what's going on server side. You have to explicitly send http requests to the server via some RESTful calls ( usually via an API or service). Then you can serve data from your back end to the front end

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings its only redirect i am asking how to use express.Router() with react-router

Comment: ` when i follow any Route on ` Can you explain what do you mean by this ?

Comment: @Panther edited

Comment: as in the first comments answer, you need to send index.html for all other routes(denotes by * as path) that is not handled by express. express will not know anything about react router or its routes. when u send index.html, react router will kick in the browser and render the appropiate page. you might also want to add a 404 page in react.

Comment: @Panther look at my server.js file i am sending index.html for everything

Comment: since express is clearly throwing 404.. your express is not sending the index.html.. so u have to make sure expreess is sending index.html as response..

Answer (score 0):

add this to your Nginx app config:

```
location /{
...
try_files $uri %uri/ /index.html
}
```